# Array Randomly Splitting String

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, windows, split

The string is being split using commas as delimiters. Every time string is printed, it appears in a different order. The String is variable:
' String: Z1,TA,H999.00,T999.00 '
 It Successfully splits, however even if the string is exactly the same, when printing the array, we get random new lines and random data missing.

When printed to Text box its either correctly split, or like:
      -Z1
      -T
    -H999.00
    -T999.
    -00
If the Loop runs again, we get different results. On the odd occasion, it is correctly displayed.

I assume its this code: (EDIT: ITS NOT)

```
 string[] ArrayCleanDataRX = CleanDataRX.Split(',');
 foreach (string EntireList1 in ArrayCleanDataRX)   
   {
   TxtZ1.AppendText(EntireList1);
TxtZ1.AppendText("\n");
}
```

Any Suggestions would be brilliant. 
Thank you.

UPDATE: (Still Unsolved) 
Update 2: More Code -

```
 #region Global Strings
    public string DirtyDataRX;                                                   //String contains Data from Serial
    public string Z1 = "Z1";                                                     //String to check if Data from serial Contains Z1
private void FeedbackProcessing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtDirtyDataRX.AppendText(DirtyDataRX);                                    //Populate TxtDirtyTest with DirtyText String   


        var CleanDataRX = DirtyDataRX;                                             //Clean Data = Dirty Text
        var charstoremove = new string[] { "|", "-", "%", " ", "  ", "   ", "~", "$", "?", "'", ".,", "..,", "..", "..:", ".:", "...", "....", ".....", "......", "......", "......", "-" };  // Contents of CharsToRemove (Removes Bad Charecters from raw serial) 
        foreach (var c in charstoremove)                                           //C is Char(s) to remove
        {
            CleanDataRX = CleanDataRX.Replace(c, string.Empty);                    //Replace C in CleanDataRX with nothing.            
        }

        TxtCleanDataRX.AppendText(CleanDataRX);                                    //Show DirtyDataRX in DirtyDataRX Textbox  

        #region IfZones and Array Loops
        if (CleanDataRX.Contains(Z1))                                                 // If CleanDataRX Contains "Z1" Run Code
        {
            string[] ArrayZ1 = CleanDataRX.Split(',');                           //New String Array from CleanDaraRX. Split using Comma as Delimiter  

            foreach (string StrArrayZ1 in ArrayZ1)                               // New string Called StrArrayZ1 in ArrayCleanDataRX 
            {
                TxtZ1.AppendText(StrArrayZ1);                                      //Append Textbox with String Array, Loop untill Empty

            }
        }

#region DirtyRX 
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,   System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        DirtyDataRX = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(FeedbackProcessing));
    }
    #endregion
```

Code i think is irelevent to the problem is left out to simplify the problem. 
Note: Some Array names have been edited slightly..

Comment: is `ArrayCleanDataRX1` a typo in your question? The variable above it is `ArrayCleanDataRX` without the 1 at the end

Comment: Thanks mate, typo, but not the problem. Nearly out of midnight oil!

Comment: Are you able to post the entire method this appears in?  This is weird enough where that might be warranted.

Comment: The RX suggests you are using reactive extensions.  Are you?

Comment: RX refers to RX data, not reactive extensions sorry. 
Here are two Examples of printed data from the array:
Z1
T
A
H999.00
T99
9.00

and......

Z
1
TA
H999.00
T
999.00

See how spaces are weirdly added in..., these are line spaces (can't use bullet lists on here? Yet, the string is always the same....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help. Problem solved on my own...
It wasn't exactly the loop, or the split...sorry.
This may help Others though......
The error was being thrown because the string was being actively built. The problem is in how the data is read in the serialport read method, this is how it was:

```
 DirtyDataRX = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
 this.Invoke(new EventHandler(FeedbackProcessing));
```

As the data coming through is line oriented .ReadLine should be used....

```
        DirtyDataRX = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(FeedbackProcessing));
```

Using ReadLine instead solves the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This peace of code is not enough to answer the question. However if you are using multithreading, you have to use locks to avoid hazardous results.

Example:

```
lock(TxtZ1)
{ 
  string[] ArrayCleanDataRX = CleanDataRX.Split(','); 
  foreach (string EntireList1 in ArrayCleanDataRX1)   
  {

             TxtZ1.AppendText(EntireList1);
             TxtZ1.AppendText("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Multithreading is not being used. Lock makes no difference, thanks. 
Can't post code as its a dissertation project.
The CleanDataRX prints its string fine, for now, it looks like this: "Z1,TA,H999.00,T999.00 "
The code I posted is supposed to split CleanDataRX using the commas as delimiters, then insert into array. Finally, printing the array

Answer (score 0):

TxtZ1 is a textbox?

Then you should rather do something like:

```
string[] ArrayCleanDataRX = CleanDataRX.Split(',');
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
foreach (string EntireList1 in ArrayCleanDataRX)   
{
    sb.AppendLine(EntireList1);
}

TxtZ1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

I think it would also solve it if you use Environment.Newline instead of \n.  Strange things tend to happen with \n in windows controls...

Comment: Although this does give results, it displays with missing data from the array. . 
When environment.newline is used like
    TxtZ1.AppendText(sb.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine); 
It still has the same problem.... :/ Thanks though.